# How to check duplicate values?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, data-structures, probability

I Need to Write a Solution That Checks for Duplicate Values (Like Birthdays) in Each Iteration and Return the Number of Iterations That Have a Duplicate value within It. If One Duplicate is Found You Can Stop The Current Iteration And Start the Next.

What Of My Solution Should Be Altered. How Should A Solution Be Written To Solve This Duplicates Problem.

```
static int runSim(int thePeople, int theCount) {

    int count = 0;

    // Runs the Sim by Count
    for(int i = 1; i <= theCount; i++) {

        List<Integer> listOfGenNums = new ArrayList<>();

        Random rand = new Random();
        rand.setSeed(i);

     ppl: for (int j = 0; j <= thePeople; j++) {

            int genN = rand.nextInt(365);

            // Add Values to Arraylist
            listOfGenNums.add(j, genN);

            // Converted ArrayList to Array
            Object[] array = listOfGenNums.toArray();

            // Check Item by Item
            for(int h = 0; h <= array.length; h++) {
                for(int k = i+1; k <= array.length-2; k++) {

                    // Checks if Index[i] is Same as Index[j]
                    if (array[h].equals(array[k])) {

                        count += 1;
                        break ppl;

                    } // End IF

               } // End Inner Loop

            } // End Loop

        } // End People Loop

    } // End Simulation Loop

    return count;
}
```

Comment: `for(int h = 0; h <= array.length; h++)` this should give you array index out of bound. QUick dirty solution would be to create a Set, go through array and add each value to set. Set's method add() returns false if value was already in set, so all you would need to do is count them.

Comment: Do you need only to know how many duplicates are in the list???

Comment: Yes If at least one Duplicate is found in the current list. then start next iteration to check a new list of values.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a HashSet. This would allow constant access to see if you have already visited the current number. If it has already been visited you can break and increment count, otherwise add it to the hashset and continue.

Here is your code rewritten to be much more efficient.

```
static int runSim(int thePeople, int theCount) {

int count = 0;
// Runs the Sim by Count
for(int i = 1; i <= theCount; i++) {
    Hash<Integer> setOfGenNums = new HashSet<Integer>();
    Random rand = new Random();
    rand.setSeed(i);

    for (int j = 0; j < thePeople; j++) {
        int genN = rand.nextInt(365);
        if(setOfGenNums.contains(genN)){
            count++; break;
        }

        listOfGenNums.add(genN);

    } // End People Loop
} //End Count Loop
return count;
}
```